# What is the virtual equivalent of physically connecting 2 NICs that are on separate devices

Tags: networking, esxi

I am looking to set up a small test bed on VMware ESXi. It would have a Firewall VM with multiple interfaces and some Desktops and Server VMs behind that firewall. My experience until now has been with their workstation product and usually I just use the NIC cards in bridge mode.

Now in ESXi, when I set up the Firewall VM with multiple interfaces(say one each for the WAN, LAN and DMZ), how or in what mode should I be setting up the different interfaces? And then how should I force the devices behind the firewall to only connect to a specific interface of the firewall and not to any other interface. I guess in short what I am asking is how do I do the virtual equivalent of physically wiring a device behind the firewall to a specific interface on the firewall. I tried searching for some guides, but all I get is extended discussions on virtual switching. I guess there is some switching involved but I cannot pinpoint exactly what I would need to do in my specific case. The guides I have read until now seems overkill for my small test bed. Please let me know if the set up is possible without any sophisticated switching involved.

Comment: Think of a cable as a passive two-port hub (or switch). Then you realize why you always end up at switching guides.

Answer (score 0):

Each interface on the firewall should be connected to a separate virtual network (vmnet).
Connect your physical network card to the vmnet connected to WAN (or whatever you want) on the firewall.
Then connect the other VMs to the vmnet connected to LAN or DMZ.